# Can I change the Weekday format to be like (Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa) in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I want to change the current week title to two letters,
eg: sun to su, mon to mo, in FSCalendar.

Comment: It seems that it's not possible seeing `configure`: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/FSCalendar/FSCalendarWeekdayView.m#L99 Else, you'd need to use `EEEEEE` dateFormat, but it's using `veryShortWeekdaySymbols` (one letter) or `shortWeekdaySymbols` (3 letters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Create a Xib and set a label or Button as per Your Requirement.

[image: First Image]

You can do this by adding a subview in fscalendar for weekDays. I ADDED SINGLE LETTER BUT YOU CAN ADD according to your requirements. 1- create View

[image: Second Image]

[image: User Nib File Like This Yhirs Image]

**Final Step**

```
let week_days_view = weekDaysView.instanceFromNib() as! weekDaysView
week_days_view.frame = self.fsCalendar.calendarWeekdayView.frame
self.fsCalendar.calendarWeekdayView.addSubview(week_days_view)
```